# parsing in korea's web site of naver

Tags: python

I have learned python for getting some data from the web.

And My major is not related with programming so It's very difficult to learn from only Internet.

I took steps just following the lecture. But I don't know how can i solve the problem.

http://datalab.naver.com/keyword.naver[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdy2A.png)

I wanna get the digit on the graph. It's the index of click volume. I just read url and then I don't know how to do it.

Is there the way to get the data??
Plz. give me answer for this question.
Oh. my version of python is 3.4
Have a good day~~

```
start = 'http://datalab.naver.com/keyword.naver'
step1 = urllib.request.Request(start, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
page = urllib.request.urlopen(step1).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
print(soup)
```